# openssl s_client and s_server cipher mismatch

Tags: encryption, openssl, sha1

I'm starting a server with:

```
openssl s_server -accept 8888 -cert server.de.crt -key server.de.key -state -cipher 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256'
```

Then connecting from the same machine with s_client:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:8888 -state -cipher 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256'
```

giving me:

```
3077933256:error:140740B5:SSL routines:SSL23_CLIENT_HELLO:no ciphers available:s23_clnt.c:469:
```

But openssl ciphers tells me it's available, and the key should also work.
When I use the same key on the same machine with apache 2.4, my browser uses ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256.
So I tried with the chrome browser to the s_server:

```
https://machineip:8888
```

And the server said:

```
CIPHER is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
```

So the s_server and the key do support the cipher, but the s_client does not?
Why?

Some more investigation shows, that only ciphers using SHA-1 for Signature seem to work in the client...

PS: I came across this issue, because my node.js websocket server seems to be limited to SHA-1 ciphers as well.

Comment: You might add the `-tls1_2` option. I seem to recall the AES/GCM ciphers are TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2. If its Ubuntu *prior* to 14, then forget it. Ubuntu disables TLS 1.2 in *clients* for interop reasons. See [Ubuntu 12.04 LTS: OpenSSL downlevel version, does not support TLS 1.2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/+bug/1256576).

Comment: thanks a lot, that worked! Even under 12.04 the option did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You might add the -tls1_2 option. I seem to recall the AES/GCM ciphers are TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2. If its Ubuntu prior to 14, then forget it. Ubuntu disables TLS 1.2 in clients for interop reasons. See Ubuntu 12.04 LTS: OpenSSL downlevel version, does not support TLS 1.2. –  jww Aug 13 at 12:42

jww was right!

It worked with the -tls1_2 option in the s_client, although I was using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Maybe the that's why I had to explicitly give this option.